# Install prebuilt packages from conda-forge (e.g. cartopy) using poetry without relying on conda (using only the channel)

Tags: python, conda, python-poetry, conda-forge

I'm testing `poetry` and I was wondering if it is possible to install prebuilt packages from `conda-forge`, as `cartopy` without relying on `conda` (so keeping a 100% poetry process). I googled this a bit but the only way I found is to install poetry *within* a `conda` venv using pip and then installing from `conda-forge` using `conda` and then tweaking poetry files to make it aware of the conda venv so that the TOML is written properly.

Packages like cartopy are a pain to install if not from a prebuilt version, if possible I'd change my conda stack to poetry stack if something like `poetry add [?conda-forge?] cartopy` works

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're looking for a way to install conda packages from `conda-forge` without using conda (as a package manager)?

Comment: @MattThompson exactly, a way to specify to poetry to use other repo than pypi (here conda-forge)

Comment: Just FYI - they (`pip` and `conda`) are different package managers (in addition to being different channels). Unless something's changed recently, poetry *only* uses `pip` and does not plan to support `conda install` (https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1856). I'll admit it's a bit weird, since they do so much in common, but they're not interchangeable.

Comment: @MattThompson yes, that was what I understood. Poetry is using pip, however you can install a _precompiled_  package as, e.g., `poetry add -D "C:\Users\wheels\GDAL-3.2.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl"`. I was then wondering if there was a way to use the conda-forge channel/website or to specify an URL instead of downloading and store locally the *.whl. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not currently possible.** Conda is a generic package manager, not just a Python package manager. Furthermore, there is no dedicated metadata in Conda packages to discriminate whether or not they are Python packages, which I think would be a prerequisite for Poetry being able to determine whether the Conda package is even valid for installation. Hence, what OP requests cannot be a thing, or at least would it be a major undertaking to make it one.

However, [others have requested similar features](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4020), so someone hopeful for such functionality could subscribe to notifications on those, or follow [the Feature Roadmap](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1856).

Comment: Ok thank you for the details. The workaround I found for know is: 1) download the *.whl of _precompiled_ packages from the conda-forge (or other) repo 2)Store them locally 3) `poetry add -D "C:\Users\wheels\precompiled_pkg_name.whl"`

Comment: Note that instead of downloading the *.whl and store it locally, one can use directly the URL pointing to the *.whl  This can already be a solution for installing pre-built packages and using poetry (delegating the validation to the user though)

Comment: @ThomasBury Just be careful. Many Conda packages are built with dynamic links that assume a Conda environment structure.